# Does the weak closure of a set S always contain the convex hull of S (infinite dimension)?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed vector space. I learned that the weak closure of $S^1=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ is the ball $\{x\in X:\|x\|\le 1\}$. I was wondering if the weak closure always contains the convex hull of the set we consider if we are in the infinite dimension vector space.

Comment: Weak and strong are  same in finite dimensions. Weak closure of $S^{1}$ is $S^{1}$ itself.

Comment: Thank you, I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let ${e_n}$ be an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space. Together with $0$ this gives a weakly closed set. Its weak closure is itself and does not contain convex combinations of $e_n$'s.

Comment: Is this reasoning correct? Suppose there is a sequence $(x_n)_n\subset \{0\}\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{e_n\}$ and  $x_n\rightharpoonup\hat{x}\notin \{0\}\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{e_n\}$ (meaning there are indexes $k,l$ such that $\|\hat{x}_k\|,\|\hat{x}_l\|\ge c>0$.Then $\forall y\in \ell^2 \sum y_j (x_n)_j\to \sum y_j\hat{x}_j$ so taking $y = e_k$ and $y = e_l$ we arrive to a contradiction.

Comment: @edamondo In any Hausdorff topological space $x_n \to x$ implies that $\{x,x_1,x_2...\}$ is a close set. In fact this is a comapct set.

Comment: Because if $y\in \{x,x_1,...\}$ and $d(y,x):=d$ so $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{N+1},\ldots \in B(x,d/2)$ and then take $\epsilon =min(d/2,d(y,x_1),\ldots,d(y,x_N))$ and $B(y,\epsilon/2)\subset X\setminus \{x,x_1,...\}$ so $\{x,x_1,...\}$ is open?